# django-admin.py makemessages -l fa doesn't crate .po files

Tags: python, django, cmd, translation, persian

i want to add fa(persian) language to my app,
i created the locale folder inside my app and a folder named 'fa' inside that. when i use the following command it runs without any errors,but doesn't create .po file(i use cmd inside my app's folder)

```
django-admin makemessages
```

it only writes this

```
processing locale fa
```

i also used this command but it didn't help

```
django-admin.py makemessages -l fa
```

i use windows 7

---

here is my models.py

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as TR
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255,verbose_name=TR('title'),help_text=TR('add title'))
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name=TR('content'),help_text=TR('write here'))
    createtime = models.DateTimeField(TR('create time'),auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False,help_text=TR('create time'))
    updatetime = models.DateTimeField(TR('update time'),auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True,help_text=TR('update time'))
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name=TR('author'), on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,help_text=TR('choose author'))
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=255,help_text=TR('add slug'))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = TR('Post')
        verbose_name_plural = TR('Posts')
```

Comment: did you create the locale folder inside your root app? Are you running the command from the root directory where your manage.py script exists?

Comment: @devdob no,i run command inside my app's folder where my models.py and views.py and ... located,and i also created locale folder there,i created a 'fa folder inside that'(i think the LC_MESSAGES folder that contains .po file is supposed to be created there)

Comment: Well you need to create your locale in your root project, next to templates and static, then you need to run the command from your project root where manage.py is. Check the notes here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/translation/#message-files

Comment: locale is in right place. i did run command there and nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem!

here is my corrected models.py

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255,verbose_name=_('title'),help_text=_('add title'))
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name=_('content'),help_text=_('write here'))
    createtime = models.DateTimeField(_('create time'),auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False,help_text=_('create time'))
    updatetime = models.DateTimeField(_('update time'),auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True,help_text=_('update time'))
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name=_('author'), on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,help_text=_('choose author'))
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=255,help_text=_('add slug'))

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class Meta:
    verbose_name = _('Post')
    verbose_name_plural = _('Posts')
```

i had imported Ugettext_lazy as TR! to prevent from ane interpositions between  "_ " s,
i was thinking that i can import as anything that i want, but when i changed "TR" into "_ " the problem has been solved